# Can HAVING evaluate a string condition

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, having

```
The following query totals sales in state= 'MA' for each salesperson.

SELECT salesperson_id, sum(sales)
FROM salesperson
GROUP BY salesperson_id
HAVING state = 'MA';


Incorrect Response : TRUE 
    
Correct Answer : FALSE
```

[Source: Hoffer et al Modern Database Management 13 ed., practice question]

The SQL statement apparently cannot display sales for state = 'MA' for each salesperson.  Without recreating this in SQL server, I imagined this will be ok.  Why would the answer be FALSE in this case?   Thanks!

Context: I am going through some practices questions for the Hoffer et al textbook Modern Database Management (13 ed.), and I'm trying to understand the answer to this question.

Comment: To filter using `HAVING` expressions must be aggregated.

Comment: It's just `WHERE state = 'MA'`

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to merely exclude any rows for any other `state`, you should place it in the `WHERE` clause. `HAVING` applies to the rows constructed after the GROUP BY (you only have `salesperson_id` & `sum(sales)` in the GROUP BY, so HAVING can only have conditions for these).

'state' must be in the `GROUP BY` for this to work; but this query is syntactically invalid. If you are not getting a syntax error it could be because `state` might be a reserved word in your dbms with a meaning/value other than 'MA', then you would get no errors, but no results, either.